# How to create events in Google Calendar through plain text with dates?

Tags: google-calendar

For now, according to this [help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), we can at best create events on Google Calendar with plain text **after we have selected a certain day**. This is rather restrictive given that I recall creating events from years ago, using strings like "Breakfast at 8 am on Saturday" and "Car maintenance 8 am, Mar 10".
[image]

Is there a shortcut on the current version of Google Calendar that can bring up a text-input field and shall convert full-text input **with dates** into an event?

---

(2021-10-31 Update) - Still, `Shift+C` only works for a given date. By default, the date is "today". With "Day View", switching to other dates does get the `Shift+C` box to create events for that date.

Comment: Any way to do this?  We have AI now...